# If a bacterium multiplies for 4 every 1 minute, in 6 mins how bacteria there will be?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If a bacterium multiplies for 4 every 1 minute, in 6 mins how bacteria there will be?

Please, could you answer this with an explanation, or the calculation you used to get to the result.

Comment: With how many bacteries did you begin the game? What have you done so far?

Comment: I do not see how this relates to linear algebra.

Comment: It doesn't, @Daniel. Already fixed, and to the downvoter: let's give this new guy a little slack.

Comment: What does "multiplies for 4" mean?

Comment: It's how I'd translate from my mother tongue "una bacteria se multiplica por 4 cada minuto" = a bacteria multiplies itself by 4 (or four times) every minute.

Comment: I have to go now, @PeterTamaroff, but I shall be back in 1 -1:30 hours, so if you're around I shall visit there.

Comment: @DonAntonio OK. I'll delete the spam.

Comment: The same bacteria will remain, but they will have had much practice with their multiplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start out with $x$ bacteria, then you get $4x$ bacteria after one minute $4(4x)$ bacteria the next, $4(4(4x))...$ therefore you get $4^6x$ bacteria after 6 minutes.

In general if bacteria multiplies itself after $1$ minute, and let $T(n)$ be the amount of bacteria after $n$ minutes will be:

$$T(n) = 4^nx$$

Where $x$ is the amount of bacteria you started with. Also, if you're familiar with computer programming, it's easy to see this with a for loop starting from $1$ to $n$.